# Haml ruby expression indentation

Tags: haml

When it gives to ruby expression, like if statement, I don't know how to indent correctly.

```
%ul
  %li foo
  - if true
    %li bar
```

The above code working, but the two `%li` doesn't aligned, which not elegant for me, become they are in the same level(I mean both are children of %ul)

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You should consider posting questions such as these on the [code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: this disturbs me too but I think the erb suggestion below is even worse. I find that I put rather small things in partials when they start to get out of hand.

Comment: @froderik I agree with you that between my suggestion and the originally code, I'd probably pick the original code, but I was trying my best to answer the question at hand.  Of available options in terms of formatting the code within a given view file, is there a better option?

Comment: I sure would like to find one! I guess these kind of things is the trade-off for getting the compactness (that we like so much!).

Comment: Hey did either of the answers, well, answer your question.  If so, maybe accept one?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet if you are concerned with formatting for readability is to escape haml with an `erb:` filter.

```
%ul
  erb:
    <li>foo</li>
    <% if true %><li>bar</li><% end %>
```

Unfortunately in situations like this the indentations kinda make the code less readable, but bare in mind the view is not mean for a great amount a logic.  As much as possible, you should use your controller and helpers to pull out logic from the view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so here is what happens in my code when the case is 'a bit' more complicated than this one:

`list.haml`:

```
%ul
  = render :partial => 'list_item', :locals => { value => 'foo', cond => true }
  = render :partial => 'list_item', :locals => { value => 'bar', cond => false }
```

`_list_item.haml`:

```
- if cond
  %li= value
```

but in a case as trivial as this I would probably not do it. Most cases tend to become less trivial eventually though.... The **con** with this approach is that you need to get to another file to see what actually happens. The **pro** is DRY.

Comment: Beautiful! I like it much better than mine.

Comment: thx - I am divided - I don't like to spread it into several files but I don't like embedded erb either